# How best to do the row groupings in GT?

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

First, I am looking at this article (https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_row_group.html). It is well written and rather clear but trying to do something that is not explicitly outlined. My first attempt is below the sample data. I can get the first grouping, Nevada, to show up. My question is how I get the other 3 states to show up in the same way?

Here is the sample data and the desired result below. I am looking to group by the area.

```
  library(gt)
  library(dplyr)

  order2 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
  area2 <- c("Nevada", "Nevada", "California", "California", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Utah", "Utah")
  estemp2 <- c(100,200,105,205,300,305,400,405)
  projemp2 <- c(110,115,210,215,310,315,410,415)

  test <- data.frame(order2,area2,estemp2,projemp2)

  testitem <- test %>% gt %>% tab_row_group(label = "Nevada", rows = order <2)
```

---

**Desired output:**

```
                        estemp       projemp
  Nevada                  100           110
                          200           115
  California              105           210
                          205           215
  Arizona                 300           310
                          305           315
  Utah                    400           410
                          405           415
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could iterate in a `for` loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
testitem <- test %>% 
   select(-order2) %>% 
   gt(rowname_col = "area2")
for(nm in rev(unique(test$area2)))
  testitem <- testitem %>%
  tab_row_group(label = nm, rows = which(test$area2 == nm))

testitem
```

[image]

---

If we don't want `tab_row_group`, just do a `group_by` and convert to `gt`

```
test %>% 
   select(-order2) %>%
   group_by(area2) %>%
   gt()
```

-output

[image]